# What do I need to know, to search for a desktop wallpaper?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment, wallpaper

I am using Linux Mint together with the `xfce` desktop environment, I honestly do not know what I have to consider in order to search for a desktop wallpaper. I am assuming that maybe which desktop environment, window manager or screen resolution I have might be important.

Could anyone help me understand what matters when searching for new desktop wallpapers?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the only thing that matters is the screen resolution. If say you display is 1280x800, then you want to find a wallpaper that matches that resolution.

If you already know your screen's display resolution, great. If not, you can use the GUI or you can also show it in terminal by using the `xrandr` command. The asterisk `*`, marks the current set resolution.

Sample Output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 inverted X and Y axis (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 261mm x 163mm
   1280x800       59.8*+
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
DVI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```